# Issues in storing and retrieving data from sqlite in android

Tags: android, sqlite, datetime

I am trying to retrieve data from the database with the following query:

```
select * from Oil Where date(DDate)=date('2012-08-07');
```

where DDate is one of the column in the Oil table with datatype text.I get the **Arrayindexoutofboundsexception**. I found that it is not returning any value the count is 0. 
can anyone help me with this.What i am actually trying is to do is store date value in the table.I couldn't find which datatype should be used to save date,from the sqlite site is that it doesn't have a particular datatype for date and time.

Comment: I fund the easiest format to save a date as is its Long value I.e getTimeInMilliseconds. Its easy to compare and there is no confusion with different regional formats.

Comment: ohk but then what if i have to find records in the range. can u provide me with the example for this @kuffs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server comes with the following data types for storing a date or a date/time value in the database:

**DATE** - format YYYY-MM-DD

**DATETIME** - format: YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS

**SMALLDATETIME** - format: YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS

```
select * from Oil Where date(DDate)=date('2012-08-07');
```

can be

```
select * from Oil Where DDate='2012-08-07';
```

Comment: i tried what u suggested yet getting same exception.i suppose it has to do with the datatype i suppose

Answer (score 0):

If you have DDate in the date format 'yyyy-MM-dd' then you can directly compare the date using

```
select * from Oil Where DDate='2012-08-07';
```

else if you have DDate in the date format 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss' then the query looks like this

```
select * from Oil Where date(DDate)='2012-08-07';
```

If you are saving date in sqlite database and you have to perform date operations like sorting or using date() and time() functions then you have to use the 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss' date format.

Datatype doesn't matter for sqlite.